# Reveal advanced settings of email account

Tags: email, nokia-lumia-535

My dad needs to access his work email. It's setup on his phone and working, but he needs it on the desktop.
But the advanced settings are hidden, and I'm going crazy trying everything to get it working.
The password, when I tap 'show password' goes from ··············· to **************, there are no incoming outgoing or port text boxes, just the remote address, username and obscured password.

And seemingly no one has come across this problem before in the history of the internet, if google is to be trusted.

It's a Lumia 535 and it's running Windows Phone 8.1

What can I do to reveal these settings!?

Comment: You cannot reveal a previously saved password (it would be a security hole if you could).

Comment: Additionally, whilst adding the account to desktop is beyond the scope of this site (and you don't specify what client, or service provider he's using), is there a reason he can't ask for this information from his employer's local friendly IT department?

Comment: Also why is there a 'show password' checkbox if what you said is true?

Comment: The show password option is there to show what you just typed, not to retrieve what was previously there. If he was fired, it might not be legal for him to access his email account for his previous employer. Regarding client/provider, if the account was hosted by Office 365, and he was using Outlook, this would be a much different process to set up than say Thunderbird.